# MODERN - Dialog does not close on ESC key

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs7

How to close and Ext JS Dialog on ESC key using modern toolkit?

Dialog does not close on ESC key.

Steps:

1 - after opening press ESC key

Result Expected
Dialog should closed

Test case
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32qp)

Seems to be a focus issue.

Comment: It seems like a bug in sencha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialogs are not focusable by default so keyboard input wont take affect until you add a focusable item or make it self focusable.

to complete, you should also use tabIndex as -1 to do the trick.

Solved it adding 2 configs on Dialog.

```
focusable: true,
tabIndex: -1
```

Thank you Guilherme Portela for helping